# Center gallery horizontally with CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a simple gallery of square thumbnails, all of them have the same dimensions. Every thumbnail is also a link. I want this entire gallery to be horizontally aligned, but "margin: 0 auto;" doesn't work. Thanks for any help!

http://jsfiddle.net/ds2uockq/

```
HTML:
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" /></a>
    ...
<div>

CSS:
#gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;`

```
#gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ds2uockq/2/)

Why did I use text-align?

> Because #gallery contains inline element i.e. `<a>`. And to center an inline-element we use text-align.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation! That was easier than I thought ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just give the width to the body and container.

CSS:

```
body{
  width:100%;
} 
gallery{
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [simple method](http://jsfiddle.net/ds2uockq/1/)

```
#gallery {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```